# Scroll to first error not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following functionin my controller

```
$scope.progress = function () {
    var form = $scope.coverDetails;
    for (i in form) {
        if ($scope.coverDetails[i].hasOwnProperty('$valid') && !$scope.coverDetails[i].$valid) {
            $location.hash(i + '-label');
            break;
        }
    };

    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.validateForm();

    if ($scope.coverDetails.$valid) {
        $location.path('/zones');
    }

    $anchorScroll();
};
```

This is kind of working. But not really.
When I click on the submit button (which calls the above function) it successfully updates the hash, however, none of the `ng-class` or `ng-show` directives update, until the 2nd press of the button, assuming `$location.hash` hasn't changed between the first and second.

an example of one of the bits not working is

```
<label id="reg-label" for="reg" ng-class="{'error': coverDetails.reg.$invalid && submitted}">
    Number plate
</label>
```

in this example, the class `'error'` isn't applied, but it will scroll to the label if the field is invalid.

anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was going on,
changing the hash causes a tempalte reload, so one has to prevent that using the following code

```
angular.module("ScrollToErrorPrevention", []).factory('$preventErrorReload', ['$route',
    function ($route) {
        return function ($scope) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                if (lastRoute.$$route.templateUrl === $route.current.$$route.templateUrl) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('locationChangedWithoutReload', $route.current);
                    $route.current = lastRoute;
                }
            });
        };
    }
])
```

and including it within the app thus:

```
angular.module('app', ['ScrollToErrorPrevention'])
```

and call the factory method from the controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller', ['$scope', $preventErrorReload, 
    function($scope, $preventErrorReload) {
         $preventErrorReload($scope);

         ...
    }
]);
```

after this, using `$location.hash(...)` along with `$anchorScroll()` works fine

The work is not entirely my own, but modified from one or 2 (more?) other sources